# How to find a pc or system using an ip address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-services, wcf

I have a web application and a desktop application and both are connected using a service.There is a functionality of taking screenshot from web application of the desktop that is running the desktop application.
I have already written the code to take screenshot.
Only thing i am stuck with is how to send the request to only that specific user?

Right now I send a request with the user id and it searches all the users that are using the application and if the user id matches it takes a screenshot.

**THIS IS THE CODE WHERE I LOOP THROUGH ALL THE USERS WHICH I DONT WANT TO DO AS IT WILL ADD ADDITIONAL LOAD WHEN THE USER BASE GROWS**

```
private void StartHttpCommandDispatcher()
        {
            mCmdDispatcher.AddResourceLocator(new ImageLocator(SMARTer.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager));
            mCmdDispatcher.AddCommand(new SpeakTextCommand());
            mCmdDispatcher.RequestReceived += new HttpCommandDispatcher.RequestReceivedHandler(OnHttpRequestReceived);
            mCmdDispatcher.Start(SCREEN_CAPTARE_URL);
        }
        private void ShowHttpRequest(string request)
        {
            NameValueCollection queryCollection = SplitNameValuePairs(request);
            string[] deatils = GetTextParameter(queryCollection);
            if (deatils != null)
            {
                _rquestedEmpUserId = Convert.ToInt64(deatils[0]);
                int CurrentEmpUserId = Client.DataService.GetEmpUserId(System.Environment.UserName);
                if (CurrentEmpUserId == _rquestedEmpUserId)
                {
                    onDemandScreenShot(Convert.ToInt64(deatils[1]), new Guid(deatils[2]));

                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way where if I send the IP address of a specific system then it will request to the same system instead of looping through all the systems?

*****Code From Desktop Application******

```
public void Start(string url)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            mListener = new HttpListener();
            // Add the prefix.
            mListener.Prefixes.Add(url);
            mListener.Start();
            mListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(this.ProcessRequest), null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Unable to start the web server.\n\n{0}", e.Message), Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    public void End()
    {
        if (mListener != null)
        {
            HttpListener listener = mListener;
            mListener = null;
            listener.Close();
        }
    }
    public void AddCommand(HttpCommand command)
    {
        Debug.Assert(!mCommands.ContainsKey(command.Name));
        mCommands[command.Name] = command;
    }

    public void AddResourceLocator(ResourceLocator locator)
    {
        foreach (string extension in locator.Extensions)
        {
            Debug.Assert(!mResourceLocators.ContainsKey(extension));
            mResourceLocators[extension] = locator;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (mListener == null)
        {
            return; // Listener is has  been closed
        }
        // Call EndGetContext to complete the asynchronous operation.
        HttpListenerContext context = mListener.EndGetContext(result);
        try
        {
            DispatchCommand(context);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Command failed.\n\n{0}", e.Message), Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            mListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(this.ProcessRequest), null);
        }
    }

    private void DispatchCommand(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

        // Inform listeners that a request has been received.
        // Only send up to 240 characters of the URL
        const int MaxNotifyRequestLength = 240;
        string unescapedUrl = request.RawUrl;
        string notifyRequest = unescapedUrl.Substring(0, Math.Min(MaxNotifyRequestLength, unescapedUrl.Length));
        if (request.RawUrl.Length > notifyRequest.Length)
        {
            notifyRequest += "..."; // Indicate the URL has been truncated.
        }
        OnRequestReceived(notifyRequest);

        string queryString = string.Empty;
        int urlEndPos = request.RawUrl.IndexOf('?');
        if (request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            if (urlEndPos != -1 && urlEndPos < request.RawUrl.Length - 1)
            {
                queryString = request.RawUrl.Substring(urlEndPos + 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            queryString = GetQueryStringFromPostData(request);
        }

        // Split query string args into name/value pairs
        NameValueCollection queryCollection = SplitNameValuePairs(queryString);

        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "text/html";
        response.ContentLength64 = 0;
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;

        // Extract a lowercase URL that doesn't include the query string.
        string url = urlEndPos != -1 ? request.RawUrl.Substring(0, urlEndPos) : request.RawUrl;
        url = url.Trim(new char[] { '/' });
        url = url.ToLower();

        // If it's a request for our dummy gif, send the dummy
        // gif image as a response and then process the actual command
        if (url.EndsWith("/dummy.gif"))
        {
            // Remove /dummy.gif from the url
            url = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 10);

            // Send the gif image
            response.ContentType = "img/gif";
            response.ContentLength64 = mDummyGif.Length;
            output.Write(mDummyGif, 0, mDummyGif.Length);
        }

        // If the url has an extension (e.g. .png) then the
        // request is for a file (e.g. an image), so see if
        // a ResourceLocator is registered to handle this extension.
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(url);
        bool foundResource = false;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
        {
            extension = extension.Substring(1);
            ResourceLocator locator;
            if (mResourceLocators.TryGetValue(extension, out locator))
            {
                locator.OutputResource(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url), extension, context);
                foundResource = true;
            }
        }
        // Not a request for a resource, must be a command
        if (!foundResource)
        {
            HttpCommand command;
            if (mCommands.TryGetValue("SpeakText", out command))
            {
                command.Execute(queryCollection, context);
            }
        }
        // You must close the output stream.
        output.Close();
    }
```

This is the Capture Link on the web application

```
<a href='javascript:var server="localhost:60024/SMARTer";var maxreqlength=1500;var EmpUserID="68675";if(EmpUserID){_bufferText(EmpUserID);_speakText()}void 0;function _formatCommand(b,a){return"http://"+server+"/"+b+"/dummy.gif"+a+"&timestamp="+new Date().getTime()}function _speakText(){var a=new Image(1,1);a.onerror=function(){_showerror()};a.src=_formatCommand("speaktext","?source="+document.URL)}function _bufferText(f){var c="true";var b=Math.floor((f.length+maxreqlength-1)/maxreqlength);for(var d=0;d<b;d++){var g=d*maxreqlength;var a=Math.min(f.length,g+maxreqlength);var e=new Image(1,1);e.onerror=function(){_showerror()};e.src=_formatCommand("buffertext","?totalreqs="+b+"&req="+(d+1)+"&EmpUserID="+f.substring(g,a)+"&clear="+c);c="false"}}function _showerror(){alert("Server is not running.")}'>Capture</a>
```

As you can see we have mentioned the EmpUserID in the link of which we want to take screenshot.

In the web.config file of the desktop application we add a key to listen to that link like this:

```
<add key="ScreenCaptureUrl" value="http://localhost:60024/SMARTer/" />
```

Comment: This is hard to answer because it is unclear how you are routing the message to take a screenshot. What is the topology? Who gets what messages, and why?

Comment: We have used HttpListener from namespace System.Net.Then we use the desktop application as the server who listens to that requests. Please check the code I have posted

Comment: so... the desktop app is acting as the web server? then presumably it is only serving requests from the local machine, yes? if so: why do you need to filter anything?

Comment: we have almost 500 people using the desktop application on their system.so when an admin requests for a screenshot of a specific person from the web application how to hit that particular server only(or that particular persons ip address)...without looping through all the 500 peoples systems and checking if the ID matched like this: `if (CurrentEmpUserId == _rquestedEmpUserId)`

Comment: what you just described isn't covered by the topology that you previously mentioned. So again: how are you currently sending messages from the admin session to the user sessions? Frankly: everything here comes down to how that piece works.

Comment: Please see the latest edit i have made to my question...I hope that clears your doubt

Comment: no, that doesn't help. I can see that the regular hook is indeed just a localhost get, so again - *and in words, not just the code*: how is the message from the admin desktop getting to the user desktops? What is the topology?